# HTML videos loading slow on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, html5-video

I have built a website with html and css. There are just 9 videos on the page. On Chrome everything works fine, but on Safari on the macBook, the videos are loading very slowly. This is the homepage I am talking about: https://janiknairz.com/ On localhost the videos are also loading fine. Could my hosting provider (host europe) be the problem? Sorry for the stupid question, but I am pretty new to this topic.

This is my html:

```
<div class="container1">
    <video
        src="Videos/1.mp4"
        poster="Thumbnails/Film 1.jpg"
        class="video1"
        id="video1"
        onclick="controlsChangeVideo1()"
    ></video>
</div>
```

And this my js:

```
function controlsChangeVideo1() {
     video1 = document.getElementById("video1");

    if ((window.innerWidth < 999 || /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) && video1.currentTime == 0) {
        video1.play();
    }
    video1.controls = true;
    const otherVideos = [video2, video3, video4, video5, video6, video7, video8, video9, video10];
    otherVideos.forEach((video) => {
        if (video.currentTime > 0) {
            video.pause();
        }
    });

    video1.onended = function () {
        video1.pause();
        video1.currentTime = 0;
    };
}
```

Comment: I tried on Safari 17, couldn't see any loading issue or lag on videos. Did you check your connection?